# Парсинг специфичного json-а регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, shell, grep

У меня есть json следующего вида (цифры для наглядности, вместо них могут быть 1+ любых символов, включая `\n`):

```json
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], 0, 0, 0]
```

Можно ли с помощью регулярки (не другого инструмента) получить первые элементы подмассивов первого массива? json всегда начинается с массива, подмассивов в этом первом массиве может быть 1+, ничего кроме подмассивов в этом первом массиве не может быть. Элементов в подмассиве может быть 1+, они могут быть любые текстовые (в том числе могут быть эскейпнутые символы, например, `\n` или `\[`, но просто `[` не может, т.к. это сломает json).

То есть в первом примере надо получить 1, 4, 7. Вот ещё примеры:

```json
[[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]] -> 1, 2, 4
[[[1], [2;v, 3], [4\], 5]]] -> 1, 2;v, 4\]
[[[test]]] -> test
```

Answer (score 2):

вы бы сделали для начала json валидным

> строка — это упорядоченное множество из нуля или более символов
> юникода, **заключённое в двойные кавычки**. Символы могут быть указаны с
> использованием escape-последовательностей, **начинающихся с обратной**
> **косой черты «\»** (поддерживаются варианты ", \, /, \t, \n, \r, \f и
> \b), или записаны шестнадцатеричным кодом в кодировке Unicode в виде
> \uFFFF.

[из вики по json](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

```
[[[test]]] --> [[["test"]]]

[[[1], [2;v, 3], [4\], 5]]] --> [[[1], ["2;v", 3], ["4\]", 5]]]
```

слешь в последнем элементе `4\]` необходимо будет еще экранировать, то есть верным будет записать так

```
--> [[[1], ["2;v", 3], ["4\\]", 5]]]
```

в общем, валидаторов **json** в интернете хватает, дерзайте

также нужно сказать что может возникнуть проблема при работе в консоли, так как в том же шеле bash сам `\` также нужно будет экранировать, то есть по итогу получим:

```
--> [[[1], ["2;v", 3], ["4\\\]", 5]]]
```

и вот, расставив кавычки для строковых значений, а также выполнив необходимое экранирование можно приступать к *вытаскиванию данных*

Разбирать **json** в консоли проще всего с помощью утилиты `jq`, да я видел что вы написали в вопросе `с помощью регулярки (не другого инструмента)` но специалисты в данном вопросе явно заняты на восьмом круге ада, поэтому

```
jq -r '.[0] | .[] | .[0]'
```

для одного из примеров выше это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$ echo '[[[1], ["2;v", 3], ["4\\\]", 5]]]' | jq -r '.[0] | .[] | .[0]'
1
2;v
4\]
```